# Firebase use PHP as index instead of HTML

Tags: php, firebase

I just deployed the website with Firebase but for some reason it only works with index.html page but not with index.php

How do I redirect to PHP or use as default?

Comment: So you deployed to the [Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/)? If so, it's static hosting only; it does not support server-side scripts like PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/

> Firebase Hosting provides fast and secure **static** hosting for your web app.

Emphasis mine. Firebase hosting does not support PHP.

Comment: OP hasn't confirmed yet but you're probably correct

Comment: Yes, after waiting for the replies I managed to find the information and that it is possible to overcome using REST API

Comment: @AlwaysConfused How do you bypass that and launch the index.php ? Would be interested